# Does it need to initialise the variable after allocating memory?

Tags: c++, memory, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement matrix multiplication in c++. I found a sample code using a class that writes in `.h` and `.cpp` files. This is just a part of the code that related to my question:

```
#include "Matrix.h"

// Constructor - using an initialisation list here
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols, bool preallocate): rows(rows), cols(cols), size_of_values(rows * cols), preallocated(preallocate)
{
   // If we want to handle memory ourselves
   if (this->preallocated)
   {
      // Must remember to delete this in the destructor
      this->values = new double[size_of_values];
   }
}

void Matrix::matMatMult(Matrix& mat_left, Matrix& output)
{
   // The output hasn't been preallocated, so we are going to do that

      output.values = new double[this->rows * mat_left.cols];

   // Set values to zero before hand
   for (int i = 0; i < output.size_of_values; i++)
   {
      output.values[i] = 0;
   }
```

I wonder why they initialised using the output matrix with 0s `output.values[i] = 0;` while it has been allocated memory before?

Comment: The initialization could be made simpler: `output.values = new double[this->rows * mat_left.cols]{};`

Comment: "_while it has been allocated memory before?_" - it makes a new allocation every time `matMatMult` is called.

Comment: I mean when we allocated memory, why do we use 0s as initial values?

Comment: That depends on what the algorithm is supposed to do. Will this algorithm do the right thing if you fill it with 1:s?

Comment: If you don't initialize it then go ahead and read the value at any index your program is malformed. it's behavior is undefined.

Comment: That seems an interesting experiment. let me check that.

Comment: Becareful your OS may make it look to be initialized however this is the first time and it won't happen if your code reuses the same memory. Also if you are using msvc in Debug mode VS will fill the heap memory with 0xcd in debug mode to try to detect your code using uninitialized variables. In release mode it does no such fill.

Comment: you cannot reliably check undefined behavior by experimenting, because it may appear to work, it is undefined

Comment: You're right. Although I tested it for other initial values and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) on `new` expression:

> The object created by a new-expression is initialized according to the following rules:
>
> - [...]
> - If type is an array type, an array of objects is initialized.
>
>   - If initializer is absent, each element is default-initialized
>   - If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is value-initialized.

"default-initialized" `int`s are colloquially not initialized. They have indeterminate values. The empty pair of parantheses refers to what Ted mentioned in a comment:

```
output.values = new double[this->rows * mat_left.cols]{};
```

Value initialization is described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). The case that applies here is

> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

---

> I wonder why they initialised using the output matrix with 0s output.values[i] = 0; while it has been allocated memory before?

Allocating memory and initializing an object are two seperate steps. Yes, the elements have to be initialzed, allocating memory is not sufficient.

Comment: So by you initialising an array after we allocate it what we are effectively doing is guaranteeing that our array holds the values that we want it to and not some random number.

Comment: @RahaMoosavi no, there are no random numbers. It is similar with non-arrays. Consider `int x; std::cout << x;`. `x` is not initialized and because of that the code has undefined behavior. You might get some number printed on the screen, it might be a `0`, but the program might also print nothing, it might erase your harddrive, it might make nasal demons fly out of your nose, etc. There are no rules that specify what the program will do, because the code has undefined behavior

Comment: Here is some info on undefined behavior: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, another quick question, when we declare a double array, we are not guaranteeing that the values this pointer is pointing to are of type double yet?

Comment: @RahaMoosavi `new` does allocate memory and create the objects, they are `double`s